# Move/copy one of the repeating events between calendars

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I have a series of repeating events in a calendar "Schedule".
I want to move a single one to my other calendar "ActuallyGoingTo".
As far as I can tell Google only allows moving/copying the whole series between calendars.

How can I move or copy one of the repeating events between calendars?

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the event "Options"->"Copy to..." you will see the event config screen and can clear the repeat settings thus making it a single event.